# Localhost is Unreachable with Wordpress

Tags: apache2, dns, wordpress

I've attempted to setup my server with a domain name but am getting a 301 error when typing the URL in the browser. (http://localhost works fine, but http://example.com yields a 301 error).

I have the DNS servers pointed to the correct public IP, and the router set to port-forward incoming 80, to local 80, to the correct private IP.

`apache2.conf` has been modified as follows

```
#<Directory /var/www/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>

<Directory /srv/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is for sake of Wordpress being installed at the suggested `/srv/www/wordpress/` and not needing the other default Apache location for a website....

`wordpress.conf` in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` folder is like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/wordpress
    <Directory /srv/www/wordpress>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /srv/www/wordpress/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, Apache 2.4.41, Wordpress 5.8.1

### Update Sept 23, 2021

Edited the title of this question from "Getting 301 Error on Apache Server" to "Localhost is Unreachable with Wordpress". Previously, I had always gotten a mere "timed out" response when entering my domain (`http://example.com`) from my local network upon which the server runs. The 301 error came when another, at that time, accessed my domain *externally*. Now that I've found a way to access my domain externally, the error is a consistent: "Localhost is unreachable". This by the way, only seems to happen on the Wordpress site; when I access the default "It Works" site, it is fine (I've uncommented the `apache2.conf` lines I highlighted earlier). Is this perhaps due to Wordpress using a database, and the default `hostname` for the user being `"localhost"`?

[For those trying to enter the domain pointing to their server: if you're doing this from the same local network upon which the server sits, it will not work (search "NAT loopback" for more on this). That's not the discussion here, but I mention it because it sunk a lot of time; `localhost` works, modifying `/etc/hosts` can do some cheats--still doens't simulate an external request from my knowledge--, but ultimately, using the domain name will not work.]

Comment: Two questions ... well ... three, but I'll stop at two: (1) Does Apache own or have permission to access the files in `/srv/www/wordpress` (2) Is AppArmor running and, if so, is it configured to allow Apache to access the contents of `/srv/www/wordpress`?

Comment: (1) is a great suggestion; I did setup Wordpress under my user ID, not the default of www-data (which Ubuntu's Apache apparently does also). I did a recursive `chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/www` to rectify that, but it didn't solve the problem. (2) I'm not sure how to check if AppArmor is configured to allow Apache, but it was running and so I stopped it briefly to check, but it also didn't yield a result.

Comment: If AppArmor was running, then there may also be modules loaded for Apache that need to be disabled: `sudo a2dismod apparmor` then `sudo service apache2 restart` may give you what you need. Ideally, though, there should not be any reason to have Apache files outside of `/var/www`, as a lot of things by default just expect Apache to live in there ...

Comment: AppArmor is not an enabled mod on my setup; the AppArmor service however, was running, then I stopped it temporarily for testing as noted. The ubuntu.com/tutorials for  installing WordPress I followed stated the /srv location.

Comment: Let's look at things from another angle, then. You can access the server from `localhost`, but not externally. A `301` is a permanent redirect. Did you install WordPress via `http://localhost` or with the domain you want to use? If `localhost` was used, then there may be a couple of things you'll need to change in the WordPress config 

Comment: If you want to see the fairly concise tutorial I followed at any point (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview) --only difference other than dependencies, was I replaced `www-data` with my user ID each instance throughout. As per your question, I guess I installed for `localhost` first, then added the `ServerName` option to the directive in `wordpress.conf` later

Comment: What I mean is I set `ServerName example.com`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix was that the Wordpress database needed to be updated. To do this:

With access to your Wordpress account, merely change the Wordpress URL and Site URL in Settings -> General:

`WordPress Address (URL): <site_URL_here>`

`Site Address (URL): <site_URL_here>`

OR

With access to you Wordpress database

1. login to mysql with the username of your wordpress site (if you forget your username, it's in wp-config.php in the root directory of your wordpress site; the corresponding password is also there)

```
mysql -u <user_name_here> -p
```

2. select the database for your site (again, wp-config.php has you covered if you forget)

```
use <database_name_here>
```

3. KEY STEP: update "home" and "siteurl" records (wordpress [official doc](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/) notes you should omit any trailing '/' on your URL)

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value="http://<site_URL_here>" WHERE option_name="home";
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value="http://<site_URL_here>" WHERE option_name="siteurl";
```

4. check the database records were just updated

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = "home" OR option_name = "siteurl";
```

That's it for that issue.

**As per being able to access your site at the new address:**

If the wordpress site is being hosted on your own local network, as noted, you will NOT be able to access it INTERNALLY, that is, from a device on the same local network (including the server); whether via localhost or even the URL you just entered in the steps above, it will not work. You can ONLY access the site EXTERNALLY (ex. from a phone using data, from some computer on a friend's network, from a computer at work, etc.). Because that's a pain, the two options I found so you can still access the site INTERNALLY are:
i) you have a router that can handle NAT loopback
ii) you use a Virtual Private Network

I have not tested (i), but I know that (ii) works because I do just that. When the VPN is on, navigate to your URL and you'll be able to see the site.

I think this point should really be made more known for tutorials about setting up and creating a Wordpress site on a local network